# How to loop 2 variables while alternating return values

Tags: java, loops, oop, return, return-value

I am just new at coding im not sure if this is even possible in my program i should be able to loop 1 - 2 - 1 - 2 - 1 - 2 alternating but im not sure what to do

what should i put inside this think function so every time i call it, it alternates between 1-2-1-2-1-2

example first time i called it think would return 1 then second time would return 2 then third time would return 1 again

```
public int think() {
    int i=1;
    int z=1;

    if(i==1){
        return i;

    }
    if(i==2){
        return i;
    }


    return i;
}
```

The code below is getting the return value of think function

```
public static String askEnemy(Enemy enemy){
    String x = "null";

    switch (enemy.think()) {
        case 1:
            x = "Hit";
            break;
        case 2:
            x = "Defend";
            break;
        case 3:
            x = "Charge";
            break;

    }


    return x;
}
```

Comment: Where is the method askEnemy called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `i` and `z` are local to the `think` method and hence they get initialized to the values you have at the start each time they get called. You cannot carry forward state using them.

You need to have a member variable in the `Enemy` class for this.

```
class Enemy {
 ...
 private int thinkVar = 1;

 public int think() {
     int thinkResult = thinkVar;
     thinkVar = (thinkVar == 1) ? 2 : 1;
     return thinkResult;
 } 
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you could have it as `-1` and `1`, you can simply write `thinkVar = -thinkVar`

Comment: `thinkVar = !thinkVar;` would only work for booleans, instead you'd need to use `thinkVar *= -1;`. To alternate between `0` and `1`, you could use `thinkVar ^= 1;`, alternate between `1` and `2`, `return (thinkVar ^= 1) + 1;`

Comment: More interestingly, for `-1` and `1` cycling, you could use `thinkVar ^= -2;`

Comment: @phflack Got it.

Comment: For those that are curious, `^` is [xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR), so `^= 1` flips the 1's bit

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from using a global variable in you main class and can send it to your other class where `think` method is developed as a parameter. Check below:

```
public int think(int value)
{
   if (value % 2 = 0)
      return 21
   else
      return 1;
}
```

Main class:

```
int value = 1;
...

public static String askEnemy(Enemy enemy){
    String x = "null";

    switch (enemy.think(value)) {
        case 1:
            x = "Hit";
            break;
        case 2:
            x = "Defend";
            break;
        case 3:
            x = "Charge";
            break;

    }
    value++;
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `think` variable inside of the `Enemy` class is needed. This way you can have multiple enemies all with different values. Otherwise, when you have one value for all `Enemy` objects then the value isn't independent for each object.

```
public class Enemy {
    private int thinkValue;

    public Enemy(){
        thinkValue = 1;
    }

    //Other functions and variables are probably in this class.

    public void setThinkValue(int value){
        thinkValue = value;
    }

    public int getThinkValue(){
        return thinkValue;
    }
}
```